# No mapping exists from object type System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label to a known managed provider native type

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

iam trying to take gridview label as parameter to update in sql as per that label but it is showing error as No mapping exists from object type System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label to a known managed provider native type. please help me thanks in advance below is my code

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnStrCCUKYC"].ToString()))
    {

        foreach (GridViewRow row in ShowGrid.Rows)
        {


            var Clientid = row.Cells[5].FindControl("lblClientid");

           // var Clientid = row.Cells[5].Text;  Clientid is coming Null 

            //Label Clientid = ((Label)row.FindControl("lblClientid")); No mapping exists from object type System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label to a known managed provider native type.

            CheckBox ckb = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("chkSelect");
            //ckb.Checked = ((CheckBox)sender).Checked;

            if (ckb.Checked==true)
            {

                var check = true;

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_InsertRecieved_HOSignaturecard ", con);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Check", check);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Clientid", Clientid);
                con.Open();
                var res = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
                if (res > 0)
                {

                    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertmsg", "alertify.alert('Data Saved successfully..!')", true);
                }

                else
                {
                    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertmsg", "alertify.alert('Data NotSaved..!')", true);
                }


            }

            else
            {

                var check = false;

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_InsertRecieved_HOSignaturecard ", con);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Check", check);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Clientid", Clientid);
                con.Open();
                var res = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
                if (res > 0)
                {

                    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertmsg", "alertify.alert('Data Saved successfully..!')", true);
                }

                else
                {
                    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertmsg", "alertify.alert('Data NotSaved..!')", true);
                }   

            }

        }

    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var lblClientid = row.cells[5].Controls[0].FindControl("lblClientid") as Label;
if (lblClientid != null)
{
    // do something if found the control...
    // e.g. assign the value to a variable
    var ClientId = lblClientid.Text;
}
```

Above code sample assumes that your ASPX markup is done correctly. If you still can't get the correct value, please provide your ASPX code in your question.

**Update**

> For UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements, the return value is the
>   number of rows affected by the command. When a trigger exists on a
>   table being inserted or updated, the return value includes the number
>   of rows affected by both the insert or update operation and the number
>   of rows affected by the trigger or triggers. For all other types of
>   statements, the return value is -1. If a rollback occurs, the return
>   value is also -1.

If your `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` returns -1, you need to check your stored procedure and see whether or not the option `SET NOCOUNT` is on/off.

For more details, please check https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx

Comment: After adding the above code still it is not working same error is occuring :'(

Comment: can you provide your aspx markup code? Need to to know where your label control is actually placed.

Comment: also make sure the variable `ClientId` in this line `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Clientid", Clientid);` is not still referencing a Label control. You need to pass a client id value as a string instead.

Comment: <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Clientid">
                                  <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblClientid" Text='<%#Eval("Clientid") %>'></asp:Label>
                            
                                  </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>

Comment: if you put a break point at this line `if (lblClientid != null)` what did you see in this variable `lblClientId`? Was it null? Also try changing your hardcoded index, 5 there, perhaps it's not using the correct column?

Comment: it wasnot null , value is coming but at res >0 it is showing res -1

Comment: ok, so that indicates the problem in your stored procedure, sp_InsertRecieved_HOSignaturecard. Please go and check if the option `SET NOCOUNT` is on in your procedure.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `ClientId.Text` in your parameter , not `ClientId`.

Comment: I have used 'ClientId.Text' but error is showing as 'res -1' but it is as (If (res>0)

Answer (score 0):

i have got answer their is no mistake in reading values of grid but the mistake is  near

**var check = true;**

it should be as **var check = "true";**

Thanks **woodykiddy** for your answers.